# Error: spawn EACCES using node-fluent-ffmpeg

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg

I'm using [node-fluent-ffmpeg](https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg) in my backend but I cant get it to set up correctly.  I set the PATHS as it instructed:

```
process.env['FFMPEG_PATH'] = '/var/task/node_modules/fluent-ffmpeg/node_modules/ffmpeg';
process.env['FFPROBE_PATH'] = '/var/task/node_modules/fluent-ffmpeg/node_modules/ffprobe';
```

But now its throwing this error:
[image]

What does this mean? I've read that its related to the permissions of the file, but i don't understand what file its talking about.

Answer (score 2):

this may help you
https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg/issues/372

all you have to do is : fs.chmod('777', function......
and it will work